# IE9 TypeError occurs while using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer

I am trying to test a web application built with angularjs in IE9 (**necessary**). However while loading the page all angular elements break and the angular expressions can be seen. The application works in chrome, mozilla and higher versions of IE. The error that is shown in IE9 is:

[image]

---

HTML

```
<div class="content-wrapper" ng-controller="LoadingController">
    <div class="container wrap-content" ui-view></div>
</div>
```

---

PARTIAL

```
...
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default notifications">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>Notifications</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="ActivityController">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr ng-repeat="activity in activities | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
                              <td class="client">
                                  <img src="images/notification.png" class="img-responsive">
                              </td>
                              <td class="message">
                                  {{activity.first_name}} {{activity.last_name}} {{activity.message}} on <strong>{{activity.created_at | notifyDate}}</strong>
                              </td>
                              <td class="buttons" ng-if="activity.type_of_activity == 'client' ">
                                  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm review-btn" ui-sref="client({id:activity.client_ucin})">View Client</button>
                              </td>
                              <td class="buttons" ng-if="activity.type_of_activity == 'workflow' ">
                                  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ui-sref="client-loan({id:activity.client_ucin,loan_id:activity.client_loan})">View  Client Loan</button>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="text-center pagination-btns">
                      <button class="btn btn-default btn-md" ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">Previous</button>&nbsp;<span style="color: #777">{{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}</span>&nbsp;
                      <button class="btn btn-default btn-md" ng-disabled="currentPage >= activities.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

---

I have searched through stackoverflow and google to find a solution to this question, but none so far. I'm literally stumped as to what could be causing this problem. I have tried adding **ui-view** as an element and appending *data* to the front of **ui-view**, didn't work. Could someone assist me in solving this issue please.

Comment: Can you try well-known method of _half-commenting_ to localize exact row or block?

Comment: @Appeiron. What do you mean by *half-commenting*? Are you saying that I should comment my code?

Comment: Not all , but try to comment one by one from deep to above. At least I had such problem with text editors. Half-commenting means - you comment half of code, so you will know in what part there is problem, then part of that part etc unless you find that sticky bug.